# Confusion about topological Hochschild homology and $\mathbb{Z}_p$-topological Hochschild homology

Tags: homotopy-theory, algebraic-number-theory, hochschild-homology

Let $R$ be the ring of integers in a perfectoid field of mixed characteristic $p$. Is $\pi_*THH(R)$ (as defined in Bhatt--Morrow--Scholze) $p$-complete (as an abelian group)?

Comment: What is your definition of $\mathrm{THH}(R,R)$? I understand $\mathrm{THH}(A,B)$ for $A$ a commutative $B$-algebra (really, $\mathbf{E}_\infty$-rings) to be defined as $A\otimes_{A\otimes_B A} A$; under this definition, $\mathrm{THH}(A,A) = A$. If $A$ is a classical commutative ring, this will rarely be isomorphic to $\pi_\ast\mathrm{THH}(A;\mathbf{Z}_p)$ (the latter will have elements in positive degrees, e.g., if $p=0$ in $A$).

Comment: @skd To be clear, in Bhatt-Morrow-Scholze, as far as I can tell, they only define $THH(R)$ and $THH(R;\mathbb{Z}_p)$, where the latter is just the $p$-completion of the former. They never define $THH(R;R)$ or $THH(R;\mathbb{Z})$ or anything like it.

Comment: @DenisNardin Yeah, that's partly why I asked. If OP meant to write $\mathrm{THH}(R)$, then the question is nontrivial.

Comment: @skd hopefully I am not saying anything inconsistent; I am using the definition of THH(-, -) which is on the first page of "Topological Hochschild homology of number rings"

Comment: @rori Ah, ok. What you write as $\mathrm{THH}(R,R)$ is what I'd write as $\mathrm{THH}(R)$, but I think this might just be a difference between the number theory and topology literature. I don't know how to answer your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the $R$-bimodule structure on $\mathbb{Z}$ then?

Comment: @DenisNardin I confused the order of $R$ and $\mathbb{Z}$; it should be the reverse. anyway, I think I have found the description of THH of integers with coefficients in an arbitrary commutative unital ring in Morrow's AWS notes

Comment: @skd are you sure? I thought the standard was: $THH^{A}(R;M)$ for R an E1-A-algebra and M a bimodule means $R\otimes_{R\otimes_AR^{op}}M$. We omit A when A=S. In particular THH(R;R) ought to mean THH(R) and THH(R;Z) would be base changed to Z. Right?

Answer (score 3):

Remark 6.1. [here](http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2019/2019MorrowNotes.pdf)  seems to imply that the answer is no: "When the input ring $A$ is $p$-adically complete (but not killed
by a power of p), then $HH(A/\mathbb{Z}_p)$, $THH(A)$, etc., as we have already defined them, will contain large
amounts of undesirable, junk data."